# Does using Parse Cloud Code is a smart move? altho it's generates more requests?

Tags: android, ios, performance, parse-platform, cloud

As simple as it could be.
Example:

I have a Class "A" at Parse that contains 500 "movie ratings". I want to calculate the average of all of them.
I have two options :

1. Fetch all the results into the user device,and calculate there.(ONE API REQUEST)
2. Use Cloud Code function to fetch all the results over the cloud, calculate THERE and send to the device "final" answer. (TWO API REQUESTS - one for the cloud code, and one for the fetching.)

What is the right way to handle this? Is there a work around?

Comment: Another option is to use an `afterSave` cloudCode trigger to update an average value that you store in another class.  Then clients can retrieve the average with a single quick,small query

Comment: @Paulw11 ya i know i just used it for example lo, you have another idea ?

Comment: That is my other idea - calculate the average on save rather than on read

Comment: @Paulw11 the real case I'm aiming to is to fetch values for a feed(like Instagram), so I can't really use the above method. What you'll do in this case?

Comment: I don't know.  Why ask a question that isn't your question.  If the value can be pre-calculated then I would do so, if it can't then it is a question of how much data needs to be transferred.  Computing in cloud code will transfer less data and therefore be faster & kinder to the user's data plan

Comment: @Paulw11 It will be a lot faster and kinder. But it will use 2 requests, which eventually if the app scales it can significantly be noticeable. So ya I wasn't clear enough. In case it cannot be pre-calculated(fetching some text and a PFFile as an image). Would you still use CloudCode, even if it adds this extra request?

Comment: It is too hard to say without knowing how often the user will retrieve the data, the size of the data and so on. Remember you have data transfer limits as well as transaction limits with parse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97513/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-paulw11).

Comment: @Paulw11 I opened chat, if it's okay lol